# how to check particular input contain dot (.) or not in magento2?

Tags: magento2, validation, zend-framework

I want to use magento2 framework validator .I'm not able to identify which function need to use.i think for this i have to use `Zend_Validate` class.

In plain php i can use following way.

```
        $pattern="/./";
        $subject="some.thing";
        preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this zend documentation this will help http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.validator.regex.html